# Smarty code not working

Tags: message-templates, smarty

Writing as a self-answered question since it may help others...

I am adding smarty code to a mail template. Including:

`{capture assign=designation}{contribution.contribution_source}{/capture}`

Later in the page, I call the variable as such:

`{if $designation}, for {contribution.contribution_source}{/if}`

But the template breaks when I try to use it. The code looks good as far as I can tell. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the space in the if-statement is `&nbsp;` rather than a normal space. For this reason, it's worth writing your smarty statements while viewing the Source code in the template editor.