# Displaying Transaction Id in Thank you letter

Tags: tokens, smarty, pdf

I am trying to create thank you letters grouping the transactions by contact. 
I am creating a table to display the contribution information but I am running into a problem with Transaction ID. since not every contribution has one, it doesn't align properly in the table. I tried using the 'line break' and 'verticle table cell' but the 
 or  is not printing for when the token is empty.

I tried to work around it by printing N/A when if the token is empty but I can't seem to get this working either 
{capture assign=temp}{contribution.trxn_id}{/capture}{if $temp ne ""}{$temp}{else}N/A{/if}

[image]

UPDATE: I tried @RayWright's suggestion and it worked for individual thank you letters perfectly. However, when grouping the contribution records by contact, the same code will only print the transaction ID when there is one and will not print NA when there isn't one...

Comment: Any chance this post is helpful? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21118/smarty-code-not-working/21119#21119

Comment: Thanks @RayWright, that solved it for individual thank you letters however it still won't work for grouped-by-contact thank you letters

Comment: @Yossi have you had a look at this related [question/answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/9131/872)

Comment: @Andrei Thank you for bringing that to my attention. It seems like the solution I am looking for but I have been trying for 1.5 hours to apply the same code for transaction id and I've not been successful yet. I don't know whether I am getting the variables wrong or if maybe the logic is different for trnx_id. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug and is documented and fixed at [CRM-21690](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21690).  You will need to apply the [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11570/files) to fix the problem or will need to wait for 4.7.30 release.

Comment: I tested your patch on 4.7.25. It seems to fix the alignment of the transaction ID. However when I use the code snippet in CRM-21690, the thank you letter is not made and I get this error (even after I cleared templates_c)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in /srv/bindings/86e9cd092c1243e3a9ebfab3cf193a7e/files/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%63/634/6343E86A%%table%3E.php on line 36

Comment: Can you please check the html message you using if it has any such chars. This error usually occurs if smarty fails to read the template or html.

Comment: you are right. The ckeditor transformed "" into its code version which included a &. Looks like the patch works!

Comment: So can this question be closed as answered??